# Truncate and drop storage in multiple tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, truncate

I wanna action a truncate and drop storage in multiple tables in oracle.
I am using the pl/SQL below :

```
BEGIN

 FOR i IN (select('LOG_'||X.TABLE_ID) AS LogTables from LOGFILE X)

 LOOP

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || i.LogTables ;

 END LOOP;

END;
```

My code works perfectly but i wanna add the 'DROP STORAGE' clause.

How shall i Proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :

```
BEGIN

 FOR i IN (select('SDE_LOGPOOL_'||X.TABLE_ID) AS LogPoolTables from SDE_LOGFILE_POOL X)
 LOOP

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE '  || i.LogPoolTables || ' DROP STORAGE' ;

 END LOOP;

END;
```